# Rails - Convert an ActiveRecord to a simple object to add field dynamically

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I am retrieving data from the database. Then I am sending it in JSON.

[image]

The thing is, I need to add dynamically a field "campaign_name".

```
def loadtimeline
    @act = Activity.order('created_at desc').paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 40)

    @act.each do |item|
      item.attributes[:campaign_name] = item.campaign.name
    end

    respond_to do |format|
      format.json do
        render json: @act
      end
    end
end
```

Finally, the moment I check client, the new field doesn't appear.

So I told myself it could be related to this object is an ActiveRecord Model. So I am trying to convert it as an object.

Is that possible or is there a way to add the field I need?

Thank you for your help.

EDIT1.
I didn't precise, but `item.campaign` belongs to an other model Campaign.

```
class Activity < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :campaign

  attr_accessor :campaign_name

  def item
    if item_path && item_id
      case item_path
        when /todo/
          Todo.find(item_id)
        when /content/
          Content.find(item_id)
        when /netlinking/
          Netlinking.find(item_id)
        else
          nil
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Your Activity model belongs to Campaign, right? (campaign_id)

Comment: So you could include the campaign in the Activity query and fetch it's name directly in view if use something like jbulder or construct it with serializer.

Comment: I'm gonna try to serialize it. Thanks!

Comment: @Anton After thoughts, It's for an ajax call. So I can't fetch its name directly in the view. I can't query every campaign for each item.

Comment: If you'll include the campaign into the Activity query it won't do N+1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could achieve this with some thing like this:

```
@act = Activity.includes(:campaign).order('created_at desc')  
acts = []  
@act.each do |item|  
  acts << item.attributes.merge({campaign_name: item.campaign.name})  
end
```

Then render the acts array.
I think using view is clearer.

Comment: I can't use view, there are too much elements to bind. It becomes very slow.

Answer (score 1):

```
a = @act.to_json
b = JSON.parse(a)
b.each do |item|
 item["campaign_name"] = item.campaign.name
end
```

or in a single line

```
JSON.parse(@act.to_json).each do |item| item["campaign_name"] = item.campaign.name end
```